# Recover Ubuntu OS after windows update/upgrade?

Tags: installation, boot

MY system had Win 7 Home Basic, after which I created separate partitions for a Linux Ubuntu installation. After doing this I had the option to choose between each OS at startup due to the dual boot.

Recently I've updated Win 7 Home Basic to Professional Edition. I have changed only the primary Windows partition and I haven't touched the Ubuntu partitions at all. Strangely, after doing the Windows upgrade, I lost access to Ubuntu. I am not prompted to login to Ubuntu during startup - I am being directly logged into Windows without being prompted.

Why is this so? Is there a way to recover the Ubuntu startup without reinstalling Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows install/upgrade process overwrites GRUB, the program which is stored on the start of your disk and which allows you to dual boot.

You can recover without re-installing, just read:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows .

Answer (score 0):

I used [SuperGrubDisk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/) in the past, a boot CD with Grub Boot Manager on it. It searches for bootable OS on your harddisk and let's you choose which one to start.

This will reinstall Grub as your bootmanager on your harddisk:

- Burn the SGD to CD, boot from it.
- Select "Detect any OS" from the SGD menu
- Choose your Ubuntu entry, boot it
- reinstall Grub with `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` (where X has to be replaced with your harddrive, most of the time /dev/sda)
- `sudo update-grub` Grub searches for other OS and recreates the bootmenu entries.
- reboot without the SuperGrubDisk in the drive